# Debugging via PyDev using Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev

Is there any step by step tutorial or guide that I can follow to use PyDev in Eclipse to debug my python code. Among the best I could find on the net is [here](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html), however it is still not well-explained how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page prior to the advanced one you linked on pydev.org is step by step, and should get you started.

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html

Comment: The strange thing is that when I run the python in debug mode, I didn't get what is expected. From the guide it mentioned "When it hits the breakpoint, it will ask you to go to the debug perspective (you should say YES to this dialog)."